# Downgrading from polkadot-v1.4.0 to polkadot-v1.3.0 gives Parachains DB has a future version (expected 3, found 4)

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-sdk

Steps to reproduce

1. Start a node with Polkadot version 1.4.0 and no specific arguments.
2. Stop the node
3. Replace the binary with version 1.3.0
4. Start the node again
5. The node don't start and prints the error Parachains DB has a future version (expected 3, found 4)

Should it be possible to downgrade versions like this?
I have never encountered this problem before on Polkadot and not on any parachains either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they didn't offer a way to downgrade the database. What I usually do is simply copy the data from the old node when this happens.

Comment: How and what do you copy in a case like this?

Comment: Just copy everything in the db dir except the db_version file?

Comment: If there are any bugs in the new version, I will downgrade my node. Additionally, if the DB version changes, I will copy the entire DB folder from other old nodes to restore its functionality.